# Microsoft Graph - Message center receive more the 100 object

Tags: powershell, microsoft-graph-api

I'm writing an application integration which message center I need to display all of them but receive only 100.

API endpoint:

```
GET https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/admin/serviceAnnouncement/messages
```

Official [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/serviceannouncement-list-messages?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http)

Is there any option to get all of the messages?

Comment: The response includes an `@odata.nextLink` property with the URI for getting the next 100 message

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the [doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/serviceannouncement-list-messages?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http#response):

> The response is paginated and each page contains 100 objects.

Anyway, you can try to use the `$top` query parameter to specify the page size of the result set.

```
GET https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/admin/serviceAnnouncement/messages?$top=1000
```

Resources:

[Paging](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/paging)